# Xubuntu 15.04 not using all Numix icons

Tags: xubuntu, icons, xfce, numix

My problem involves a few application icons that won't use the numix-circle-icons package for their app icons when active. When browsing the application manager, I can view the numix icons fine, but once opened, they switch to their hideous default icons. Like so...

[image]

If you look closely, you'll see that Chrome and Spotify both use their stock icons, not Numix circle. Any way to fix this?